# Calling JavaScript external function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm editing an existing JavaScript jQuery library. I want idea on how to call an external JavaScript function into the HTML.

The JavaScript function is like this:

```
AblePlayer.prototype.setDimensions = function() {

    if (this.$media.attr('width')) {
      this.playerMaxWidth = parseInt(this.$media.attr('width'), 10);
    }
    if (this.$media.attr('height')) {
      this.playerMaxHeight = parseInt(this.$media.attr('height'), 10);
    }
    // override width and height attributes with in-line CSS to make video responsive
    this.$media.css({
      'width': '100%',
      'height': 'auto'
    });
};
```

How can I call this inside of my HTML?

Comment: `AblePlayer` is a type, so you can just call the method on an instance of that type. e.g: `var player = new AblePlayer(); player.setDimensions();`. Note that it's not clear on the constructor of that type (about the arguments, so I just give a simple example about one not accepting any).

Comment: thank so much for this idea I will try this one. thank you thank you :)